# Passing environmental variables to zipkin helmchart

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-helm

I am running zipkin in K8s from a helmchart and it is working fine but I am trying to change the Zipkin storage type to be 'elasticseasrch'. Is there a way to pass the required environmental variables (i.e. `STORAGE_TYPE`) to the helmchart?

I tried below commands with no luck.

```
helm install --set zipkin.env.STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch,zipkin.env.ES_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch.hshf:9200 zipkin-saas repo/zipkin
```

I am using zipkin helmchart with the following details:

- APPLICATION VERSION 2.21.0
- CHART VERSIONS 0.2.0
- Helm repo: https://carlosjgp.github.io/open-charts/
- installation commands (default installation without the environmental variables):

---

```
helm repo add carlosjgp https://carlosjgp.github.io/open-charts/
```

---

```
helm install my-zipkin carlosjgp/zipkin --version 0.2.0
```

Comment: Can you also share the helmchart repo link here please.

Comment: I have updated the question to have the repo URL and installation commands as well.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this chart and after quick examining of its content it looks like it doesn't provide the ability of setting those variables. So although you're able to provide those additional variables with `--set` parameter, helm doesn't know what to do with them as the chart is not designed to accept them.

Alternatively you can download the chart by running:

```
helm fetch carlosjgp/zipkin
```

Then extract it:

```
tar xzvf zipkin-0.2.0.tgz
```

And now you may edit it manually. Suppose you want your variables to be available in `ui` pods which are defined in a deployment. You may edit the file:

```
zipkin/templates/ui/deployment.yaml
```

and add your env variables in the `env` section along with what is already present there and defined as a template:

```
      env:
        - name: ZIPKIN_BASE_URL
          value: {{ include "zipkin.collector.service.uri" . | quote }}
        - name: STORAGE_TYPE
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: ES_HOSTS
          value: http://elasticsearch.hshf:9200
```

Then you can install it from the the local files:

```
helm install zipkin-saas ./zipkin
```

And now when you connect to your zipkin ui pod:

```
kubectl exec -ti zipkin-saas-ui-6657d894c8-ssxs9 -- /bin/sh
```

you will see that your variables are set:

```
/ # echo $ES_HOSTS
http://elasticsearch.hshf:9200
/ # echo $STORAGE_TYPE
elasticsearch
/ #
```

Comment: I don't try the solution suggested by mario yet. But as a workaround I added the (--dry-run) option to get the yaml will be executed by helm chart and executed them manually after adding the storage type. I will try to follow mario's suggestion at the earliest and update you and accept the answer if it goes well.